# Handling NaN / Inf in a numpy dnarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-indexing

Working on a 4D numpy array (array of arrays). Each nested array is of shape `(1, 100, 4)`

```
trainset.shape
(159984, 1, 100, 4)
```

But then within the nested arrays, are found some `nan` values which I would like to handle. For example the first nested array in `trainset` contains such:

```
trainset[0]
array([[[ 7.10669020e-02,  4.91383899e-03, -1.43700407e-02,
          1.52228864e-04],
        [ 7.59807410e-02, -9.45620170e-03,             nan,
          1.35892100e-04],
        [ 6.65245393e-02,             nan,             nan,
          8.98521456e-05],
        [            nan,             nan,             nan,
          1.41090006e-05],
        [            nan,             nan,             nan,
          6.68319391e-06],
        [            nan,             nan,             nan,
         -3.27272689e+01],
        [            nan,             nan,             nan,
         -1.09090911e+01],
        [            nan,             nan,             nan,
          8.25973981e+01],
        [            nan,             nan,             nan,
          1.12207785e+02],
        [            nan,             nan,             nan,
          1.65194797e+02],
        [            nan,             nan,             nan,
          2.25974015e+02],
        [            nan,             nan,             nan,
          2.78961026e+02],
        [ 3.87926649e-03,  1.81274134e-04, -1.08764481e-03,
          3.41298685e+02],
        ...
        [ 4.06054062e-03, -9.06370679e-04,  1.30517379e-03,
          3.10129855e+02]]])
```

How do I check all arrays in `trainset` for `nan` values and where found, replaces that with column's median value?

**EDIT**

Using:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')

for data in trainset:
  trainsfrom_data = imp_mean.fit(trainset)

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

gives the indicated error, as above.

Comment: [`numpy.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html), not sure how to replace with median of row.

Comment: maybe `trainset[np.isnan(trainset)] = np.median(trainset,axis=1)` but that would probably give axis error? I should probably learn how numpy works. 

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen median of column. As suggested, I can use SimpleImputer, but I'm not sure how to reshape a 4D to 2D then later reshape back, preserving the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html), and select the `median` imputing strategy. I am not sure if `nan` are replaced column-wise or row-wise, you may have to reshape your array before passing it through the `SimpleImputer()`, and then reshape it back.

To your edit: reshape array into 2D, preserving column size, and then make a reshape to original form. Also, use `fit_transform` for every column to get the result in one go. Reshape will be something like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(15, 1, 100, 4)
print(A.shape)

init_shape = A.shape

B = A.reshape(np.prod(init_shape[:-1]), init_shape[-1])
print(B.shape)

# SimpleImputer goes here

B = B.reshape(init_shape)
print(B.shape)
```

Comment: can you please add a code snippet showing how to reshape to 2D? Probably I do not need to navigate `trainset` like `for data in trainset:` I can go ahead to reshape `trainset` perform imputation and reshape it back.

Comment: Added some reshape example, hope it helps.